# What affect does a small amount of alcohol have on blood pressure?

Tags: blood-pressure

The internet has all sorts of information on heavy alcohol use ( it is bad). But I am wondering about a couple drinks , that is a total of 25 ml of ethanol.There is some information that it dilates blood vessels that would lower blood pressure but nothing specific. For an old( 80 +) male in relatively good health taking no routine prescription meds.

Comment: Male? Female? Sick? Healthy? Old? Young? On medication? Preexisting conditions? This is...very broad, can you narrow the focus down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In summary,** moderate alcohol consumption (up to 2 drinks/day for males) does not seem to be associated with significant changes in blood pressure. Acute alcohol intake dilates the arteries in the skin, which suggests that it could lower blood pressure, but because of the compensatory mechanisms, such as an increase of heart rate, the blood pressure can actually rise a bit ([Am J of Hypert](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15752957)).

1) [Alcohol’s Effects on the Cardiovascular System (Alcohol Research, 2017)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5513687/):

> In healthy adults, consuming **low-to-moderate amounts of alcohol each
>   day typically has no short-term (i.e., acute) or substantial impact on
>   hemodynamics or blood pressure (BP).**

2) [The effect of a reduction in alcohol consumption on blood pressure: a systematic review and meta-analysis (Lancet, 2017)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29253389):

> In people who drank two or fewer drinks per day, **a reduction in
>   alcohol was not associated with a significant reduction in blood
>   pressure.**

3) [Systematic review of the effect of daily alcohol intake on blood pressure (American Journal of Hypertension, 2005)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15752957):

> The review demonstrated a significant **rise in systolic blood
>   pressure (SBP) and diastolic BP (DBP) of 2.7 mm and 1.4 mm Hg,
>   respectively, after alcohol intake.**

In the above review, the term "significant" is a statistical term, but to me, 1.4-2.7 mm Hg rise of blood pressure does not sound like "a lot."

4) [Scientific Report of the 2015 Dietary Guidelines Advisory Committee](https://health.gov/dietaryguidelines/2015-scientific-report/PDFs/Appendix-E-2.26.pdf):

> There is strong and consistent evidence that in healthy adults
>   increased adherence to dietary patterns scoring high in fruits...and
>   **moderate in alcohol is associated with decreased risk of fatal and
>   non-fatal cardiovascular diseases,** including coronary heart disease
>   and stroke.

The above guidelines suggest that moderate alcohol consumption is not typically harmful for the circulatory system.